# Why does namespace usage break MinGW compilation?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, separation-of-concerns

Through the act of separating a set of input and output related functions from other parts of a program, I have encountered a problem with compiling files when functions in a header are placed within a namespace. The following files compile:

> main.cpp

```
#include "IO.h"
int main()
{
    testFunction("yikes");
}
```

> IO.h

```
#ifndef IO_H_INCLUDED
#define IO_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>
void testFunction(const std::string &text);
#endif
```

However, **when `testFunction` is placed in a namespace:**

```
#ifndef IO_H_INCLUDED
#define IO_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>

// IO.h
namespace IO
{
    void testFunction(const std::string &text);
}
#endif
```

within IO.h, and then invoked as `IO::testFunction`, **compilation fails,** throwing

```
undefined reference to `IO::testFunction(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

In each case, IO.cpp is

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
void testFunction(const std::string &text)
{
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
}
```

and the compilation command is `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp IO.cpp`, with the compiler being x86_64-w64-mingw32 from TDM-GCC, on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: You need to put your implementation into the namespace aswell. `void IO::testFunction(...) { ... }`

Comment: Your base examples are good, but you should add what the code now looks like after addign the namespace so that we can see exactly what you are doing. @Kanjiu is very likely correct, but there is no way to be certain without a complete example of the "after" code.

Comment: Groovy. Thank you. This proves out @Kanjiu 's hypothesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the declaration of your function to be in a namespace you need to implement the function within this namespace aswell.

The signature of your function will be `IO::testFunction(...)` but you only implemented `testFunction(...)` so there is no implementation for `IO::testFunction(...)`

The header file (IO.h):

```
namespace IO {
    void testFunction(const std::string &text);
}
```

The cpp file (IO.cpp):

```
#include "IO.h"

// either do this
namespace IO {
    void testFunction(const std::string &text) { ... }
    // more functions in namespace
}


// or this
void IO::testFunction(const std::string &text) { ... }
```

Comment: `namespace IO { ... }` works, but oddly the second option does not, with MinGW throwing `error: 'IO' has not been declared` at compilation. Why is this?

Comment: @MushroomMan does `IO.cpp` include `IO.h` so the compiler can see the declaration of `namespace IO` before it sees the `IO` in `IO::testFunction()`?

Comment: I added the include to my answer as well @RemyLebeau

Comment: @RemyLabeau Alas, it does not; that was the problem, thank you.